# Create Keras Custom Loss Function with Different Goals

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a custom loss function for a neural network in Keras. The model must be trained to predict quaternion (a specific vector with four elements)

```
Y_pred = [w x y z]
```

Y_true and Y_pred are quaternion and the error is calculated by quaternion multiplication:

```
Error = Y_true * inverse(Y_pred)

Error = [w_err x_err y_err z_err]
```

Ideally, the first element must be 1 and other elements must be 0:

```
Error = [1 0 0 0]
```

How can I create such a custom loss function?

PS
The inverse is calculated by

```
inverse(Y_pred) = [w, -x, -y, -z]
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the function `inverse()`?

Comment: and the whole loss is the sum of the `Y_true * inverse(Y_pred)`? also, your NN is predicting `[w, -x, -y, -z]`?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia the loss is Error = [w_err x_err y_err z_err] = Y_true * inverse(Y_pred).
And inverse(Y_pred) = [w, -x, -y, -z]

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin If Y_Pred = [w x y z] the the inverse(Y_Pred) = [w, -x, -y, -z]

Comment: the loss by definition is a single value, can't be a vector, that makes no sense

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia how can I use a vector instead of a single value?

Comment: you can, but makes no sense, we are not physicists, we have no idea on the distributions on those values, you have to understand that you have to explain your problem to a programmer, not to a physicists, so you have to give as much infos as possible, such as the domain of the values, what is inverse and so on, and not in the comment section, but editing your question and well-formatting those new informations

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Sorry for that I edited the question

Comment: what are the domains of the variables? also, given an exact solution, `[w,x,y,z] * [w,-x,-y,-z] = [w^2, -x^2, -y^2, -z^2]` which does not match the `[1,0,0,0]` that you have reported